# Android support-v7 appcompat v22 Button Style and Toolbar Issue in Android 4

Tags: android, button, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm facing a problem with appcompat v22 with at least android 4.4 on Android Studio Designer and Samsung Galaxy S4. As you can see on the picture below the two white areas are buttons with default style. I used the default Theme.AppCompat. The correct buttons above are ImageButtons. As you can see the buttons are white, the button text is white and they have no touch feedback at all, as if the background ressource is missing.

[image: White Buttons with white Text on no touch Feedback]

I have a similar problem with the text selection toolbar what ever Theme I choose the toolbar has white icons on a white background.

I'm wondering that I could not find any other problem like that, cause it looks like as if this is a problem within the support repository.

and last but not least, when targeting android 22 (5.1) nothing is shown at all in the android studio designer cause of this error message:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr

I would appreciate any ideas to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with support_v7:appcompat rev 22.1.0 (22.04.2015)

Answer (score 2):

See [AOSP issue 160591](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160591) for more information regarding this problem.

Comment: thx @qbix, looks like it has been resolved today by the new appcompat release

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue too. And what's more, the action bar color is also reversed. This seems to be a support library v22 problem.

I had to turn back to v19.

Comment: Also fixed in v22.1, blog post here http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Comment: Are you sure it is fixed? I have just upgraded to v22.1 and the problem is still there.